# Conspiracy (Diplomacy Android app) possible bug or rules misunderstanding?

Tags: diplomacy

I am using the app Conspiracy for Android to play Diplomacy with my friends. I would like to know whether there is a bug or I am misunderstanding rules.

**Spring 1901**

Germany

- F kie-hol
- A ber-kie

France

- F bre-ENG

**Fall 1901**

Germany

- F hol-NTH
- A kie-hol

**Spring 1902**

England

- F edi-NTH
- F lon S F NTH

Germany

- A hol-lon
- F NTH C A hol-lon

France

- F ENG S A hol-lon

The rest hold every turn.
According to the simulation, every movement is negated in Spring 1902.
In my opinion, *A hol-lon* should not be negated. Am I right?

Comment: Are these all of your actions only?  What are the other players actions?

Comment: It's based on the classical setup. If you simulate it you can deduce which team makes every move. However I'm editing the post adding the teams

Comment: Edited. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes.  It is more clear.

Comment: ENG F lon S F NTH is supporting the German Fleet in the North Sea?

Comment: If by ENG you mean England player, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, there was a problem with the resolution engine to manage this kind of situation in Conspiracy.

I've worked on it and it's now fixed. From now on the server has been updated and all the next resolutions will be managed correctly. In application side, the analyse engine will keep displaying this error as long as players are using the version 2.9.0 and lower. I invite anyone to update their application to the new version (v2.9.1), it's available in the PlayStore from March 21st 2020.

Thank you for reporting me this problem.

Here are screenshots that show you how things is now managed :[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the rules of Diplomacy:
https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/ah/diplomacy_rules.pdf

Which may be different from the game Conspiracy:
http://badfrog.info/conspiracy/home/

With the orders as written, Holland should successfully dislodge London.  The convoy holds and the attack is supported from the English Channel.

Results According to Conspiracy:
Orders:
[image]

Resolution:
[image]

Results According to RealPolitik:
Orders:
[image]

Resolution:
[image]

Comment: Conspiracy is an app made by fans of Diplomacy for fans of Diplomacy to play Diplomacy (as they state) so I'm pretty sure it's a bug. I will try to report it. Thank you

Comment: Apparently I can observe the game in the app, what is the name of the game?  Or a username?

Comment: It was not from a game but just a simulation. First, observe a random game with the classical (7 players) map. Next, hit the three-dotted button top right and Analysis. Then, top left choose Spring 1901 and then run the simulation as I wrote here. You can press the button on bottom right to pass to the next turn (in Analysis mode)

Comment: @user459312 I have done it now.  Agreed it's a bug.  If lon holds instead it gets dislodged.

Comment: I've just sent an email to report the bug. Hope it will be read soon. Thanks for the help